# template class default type and condition

Tags: c++, templates, default, enable-if, conditional-types

I want to use std::enable_if for MyClass in order to accept only (uint32_t | uint64_t) and at the same time if the user did not provide any type; a default one is picked according to bellow  condition.

but I can't get it to work.  (C++17)

```
#include <vector>
#include <cstdint>

template <typename T=std::conditional_t<sizeof(void*) == 8, std::uint64_t, std::uint32_t>>
class MyClass
{
  private:
    std::vector<T> vs;
  public:
  // ...
};


int main(){
  MyClass a; // OK, the defaut type is used either uint32_t or uint64_t
  MyClass<std::uint32_t> b; // Ok, use the user provided type
  MyClass<long> c; // must not compile, T is not one of uint32_t, uint64_t
}
```

Comment: And what would you do if size of a pointer is smaller? Admitted, they get rare, but there are still some 16-bit µC out there... (sure, uint32_t works for these as well).

Comment: I personally would prefer the test `sizeof(void*) == sizeof(uint64_t)`. Admitted, again rare, but some specialised machines even today have `CHAR_BIT == 16`...

Comment: What's actually the reasoning behind limiting the width of the type? Maybe something like `std::is_integral<T> && std::is_unsigned<T>` is preferable? `std::uintptr_t` could be a good default then, and a user might even use a 128-bit unsigned integer on system/compiler providing one...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add [`static_assert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert) to perform the checking.

```
template <typename T=std::conditional_t<sizeof(void*) == 8, std::uint64_t, std::uint32_t>>
class MyClass
{
  static_assert(std::is_same_v<T, std::uint64_t> || std::is_same_v<T, std::uint32_t>, "T must be std::uint64_t or std::uint32_t");
  private:
    std::vector<T> vs;
  public:
  // ...
};
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/IFqR4Y2eE0A2EpHq)

Answer (score 0):

The solution proposed by songyanyao with `static_assert` is good, totally valid and shorter than what I suggest below. Yet...

Suggesting another alternative, letting the compiler check you without a need for `static_assert`:

```
template <typename T>
class MyClassBase {
    std::vector<T> vs;
  public:
  // ...
};

template <typename T =
            std::conditional_t<sizeof(void*) == 8, std::uint64_t, std::uint32_t>>
class MyClass;

template <>
class MyClass<std::uint64_t>: public MyClassBase<std::uint64_t> {};

template <>
class MyClass<std::uint32_t>: public MyClassBase<std::uint32_t> {};
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/66033e773f001379

Comment: That's nice if no `static_assert` is available for whatever reason. OK, `std::conditional` then likely is not either, but that's easy to implement on one's own. Drawback: One has to maintain two implementations.

Comment: @Aconcagua `static_assert` means that the type _can be created_ but we forbid it via `static_assert` **somewhere in the code**. Suppose someone at some other compilation unit adds the explicit specialization `template <>
class MyClass<long> {};`. One may be tempted to think that the `static_assert` forbids it, but it doesn't. In my approach the type just doesn't exist unless you would create it. No magics. But again, both ways are valid.

Comment: And what's *effectively* the difference? *Both* approaches allow to use the templates only with the two types desired, and *both* approaches allow to circumvent the (desired!) limitation by adding yet another specialisation. I'm well aware of the technical differences behind, but that wasn't my point – rather that you could use your approach, too, when forced to compile for C++03 or older, while the other one not. And such limitations exist even today, after almost ten years of C++11...